# Windows privileges needed to close a external app

Tags: c++, windows

I need to close some external programs.

Does my app require admin privileges to use Windows API **GetWindowThreadProcessId**, **OpenProcess** and **TerminateProcess** or user mode is enought?

I've checked in XP and 7 and works fine, but I know newer versions are more restrictive.

I'm using the following code:

```
bool CloseApp(const char *WindowName)
{
  HWND hWnd;
  hWnd=FindWindow(nullptr,WindowName);
  if(!hWnd)return(true); // Not running

  DWORD pid;
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd,&pid);
  if(!pid)return(false);

  HANDLE prc;
  prc=OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE|PROCESS_TERMINATE,FALSE,pid);
  if(!prc)return(false);

  TerminateProcess(prc,0);
  DWORD rst=WaitForSingleObject(prc,10000); // Wait until completion
  CloseHandle(prc);

  if(FindWindow(nullptr,WindowName))return(false); // Check if still running

  return(true);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: in general all what you need `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` in your token. and enable it before call `OpenProcess`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on your application and the external process you want to kill. Windows has a pretty complicated system of authorizations for process interactions (everything revolves around [`Access Tokens`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/aa374909(v=vs.85).aspx)).

## Process

Since Windows Vista, process now have an [integrity level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/library/bb625957.aspx) which can be :

- `Untrusted`. No logon SID, no access to the filesystem. Basically a pariah.
- `Low`. Can only access `%LocalLow%` and a restricted set of API. Usually used to sandbox dangerous parts of an application (parsers, evaluators, etc.)
- `Medium`. Your run-of-the-mill application/user
- `High`. Superior privileges. Need `UAC` confirmation.

As you can imagine, lower integrity level applications can not interfere with higher integrity level ones. Since this mechanism is rarely used by developers (apart from MS products and web browsers) I assume your program run as `Medium`.

From integrity levels analysis, your program can probably only terminate process created by **the same user** and without **admin privileges**.

## Services

Services are long-term process that have they own set of access mechanism. Services usually require admin levels (or even `SYSTEM`) to be controlled and terminated. Some can even be modified only by Network admins (e.g. in a AD) or only by Windows itself (e.g. for [`PPL` services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/dn313124(v=vs.85).aspx))

Anyway, the best way to check it is to call `OpenProcess` with your arguements and, if the calls fails, retrieve the last error set (using `GetLastError()` and check check for the `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (0x5) value.

Comment: I need to kill a process not a service, and yes, you are right: my app run as user (medium).

Comment: then what I've written in bold holds true.